# Edit JSON file while keeping it properly formatted (e.g. indentation)

Tags: python, json, matlab

I have a JSON file with the format below and I would like a method to easily edit the data in the two datasets.

By having the tables to insert (2 columns each) in a .txt or .xls file how can I easily replace the two data tables [x,x].

I tried to do it with jsondecode and jsonencode funcions in MATLAB but when I rewrite to a .json file all the identation and line changes are lost. How (and with which software) can I do it to keep it properly formatted?

```json
{
  "Compounds" :
      [ "frutafresca" ],
  "Property 1" : 
      {
      "Scheme" : "Test1"  ,
      "StdValue"  : 0.01                 ,
      "Data":
          [
            [     353.15  ,   108320   ],
            [   503.15  ,   5120000  ],
            [   513.15  ,   6071400  ]
          ]
      },
  "Property 2" : 
      {
      "Scheme" : "Test 1"  ,
      "StdValue"  : 0.01                 ,
      "Data":
          [
            [     273.15  ,   806.25 ],
            [   283.15  ,   797.92 ],
            [   293.15  ,   789.39 ],
            [   453.15  ,   598.39 ],
            [   463.15  ,   578.21 ],
            [   473.15  ,   556.79 ]
          ]
      }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to preserve the formatting?

Comment: Because then I store the files for archive and they are much easier to read than if everything is in the same line.

Comment: Why would everything be on the same line though? You don't want to preserve the formatting, you just want human readable output, no?

Comment: Yes, but with the MATLAB functions I mentioned not even the line changes are preserved and everything is written on the same line.

Comment: _Yes, but with the MATLAB functions I mentioned not even the line changes are preserved and everything is written on the same line._ Ah, unfortunately I don't know much about MATLAB, so I won't be able to help with that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason not to use the standard lib `json` module?

## `json` module

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump):

> `json.dump(obj, fp, *, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, cls=None, indent=None, separators=None, default=None, sort_keys=False, **kw)`
>
> If indent is a non-negative integer or string, then JSON array
>   elements and object members will be pretty-printed with that indent
>   level. An indent level of 0, negative, or "" will only insert
>   newlines. None (the default) selects the most compact representation.
>   **Using a positive integer indent indents that many spaces per level**. If
>   indent is a string (such as "\t"), that string is used to indent each
>   level.

```py
import json

data = None
with open('data.json', 'r') as _file:
    data = json.load(_file)
assert data is not None


## do your changes to data dict


with open('data.json', 'w') as _file:
    json.dump(data, _file, indent=2)    ## indent output with 2 spaces per level
```

Comment: The only reason why I mentioned MATLAB is because it is what I know best. But as I am interested in learning python I will give this a try!
Thank you!